# mjpeg @ 0x27ee9e0 buffer smaller than minimum size: How to create a video file with size less than the minimum buffer size?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am new to opencv and I am trying to create a video file with frame size 56x72 using opencv-python. I am using 'MJPG' to encode the video with a frame rate of 20. I get an error which says - [mjpeg @ 0x27ee9e0] buffer smaller than minimum size.

I checked the avcodec.h file and it says that the FF_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE = 16384 and it verifies if the buf_size is at least FF_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE and i think the buf_size is width*height*4 (i am not really sure of this).

So does it mean that I can't create a video file with frame size 56x72 or smaller? Is there any way around?

Comment: The `ffmpeg` cli tool creates 56x72 (M)JPEG video or image just fine, so the issue is likely either your code, or perhaps you are using an ancient FFmpeg, or both, or something else completely...

Comment: Thanks for the response LordNecbeard. I am able to get images of that size. But when I try to write them to a video it fails and I installed 2.5.4 ffmpeg. But I am not sure if opencv uses those libraries as i think it uses its own dependency libraries (from the 3rd party folder).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using opencv2.4 also when using other codec than MJPG. After upgrading to version 3.1.0 the error doesn't occur anymore.