# OpenCV VideoWriter create empty file

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV VideoWriter.

Currently I have 2 projects: one in C# and one in C++.

C# project will read *.bmp file, create bitmap list then call writeVideo function in C++ project.

In C++ project, I am using VideoWriter with MJPG codec, read bitmap one by one from bitmap list, convert to mat, add to cv::VideoWriter object, then use video.release().

All *.bmp files are 101x76.

It works when the folder has 53 files. Otherwise, when the folder has less than 53 files, it doesn't work (output file cannot be opened).

Here is my code:

```
int s = bmList->Count;
int w = bmList[0]->Width;
int h = bmList[0]->Height;

cv::VideoWriter video(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(path), CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 10, cv::Size(w, h));
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
    IplImage* temp;

    System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bitmapData = bmList[i]->LockBits(System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, bmList[i]->PixelFormat);

    temp = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    temp->imageData = (char*)bitmapData->Scan0.ToPointer();

    bmList[i]->UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat();

    cv::cvtColor(cv::Mat(temp), mat, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    video << mat;
}

video.release();
```

Do you know about this problem? Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post your code and also the error message that you are getting

Comment: There is no error message, wrong format video is 6KB and cannot be opened. Sorry, I cannot post the code because of privacy.

Comment: make sure that you application has access to opencv_ffmpeg*.dll

Comment: @Danie If your original code is under privacy try to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can help you. We wont guess what is going wrong. Btw simple code snippets (basic stuff) can't be under privacy espesially if you rename private data.

Comment: I just updated the code. I tried "MSVC" codec and it works. I think the problem is "MJPG" codec or alpha channel of bitmap data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found same problem here: [mjpeg @ 0x27ee9e0 buffer smaller than minimum size: How to create a video file with size less than the minimum buffer size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819758/mjpeg-0x27ee9e0-buffer-smaller-than-minimum-size-how-to-create-a-video-file-w)

It means input buffer is smaller than minimum size. I upgraded OpenCV to 3.1.0 and it worked.

Thank you, everyone, for your support!